# Verify graphql query

Tags: graphql, apollo

I'm building a simple platform using graphql as api gateway and a frontend that send some queries to this api, I'm blocked on how can I validate a query before run it to avoid malicious query to be ran. I was thinking to use [persistgraphql](https://github.com/apollographql/persistgraphql) but I just noticed that is now archived so I'm not sure if it's a good idea to use it, the second problem is that the api and the frontend are in 2 different repo so I didn't find yet a solution to whitelisting the query in the frontend and use this whitelist in the api...what's the best solution to whitelist a query with graphql?

Comment: What sort of "malicious" queries are you trying to avoid?

Comment: this is not my case in particular but it is good to explain the reason behind my question, let's say we have a list of user with different props (email, name, surname, password, ecc...) and I want to display the name of my user, I'll run a query asking for name and surname, but anybody can simply get the query and add email/password and get them too...(the psw usually is encrypted but still is not good)...that's why I was thinking to use a whitelist of query...

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is limiting access to certain fields based on *who* is making the request, then you should implement some kind of authorization strategy. You can populate the context with information about the logged in user and then use this information inside your resolvers for the fields you want to protect to determine whether the value of the field should be returned or not.

```
const resolvers = {
  User: {
    somePrivateField: (user, args, ctx) => {
      // Make sure the request is from a logged in user and the user making the
      // request is the same as the requested user OR the user is an admin
      if (ctx.user && ( ctx.user.id === user.id || ctx.user.isAdmin )) {
        return user.somePrivateField
      }

      // throw an error or just return null or undefined to resolve the field to
      // null in the event authorization fails
    }
  }
}
```

More sophisticated strategies are possible using [directives](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/security/authentication/#authorization-via-custom-directives) or existing libraries like [graphql-shield](https://github.com/maticzav/graphql-shield).

Of course, certain fields that may exist on your database model -- like passwords -- should probably never be exposed in your API in the first place.

Comment: mmm ok, this make sense but I preferred to have some persistent queries whitelist, but probably I'll go for this way...thanks!